# e4 RCP: Manipulating Menu when switching between perspectives

Tags: java, rcp, perspective, e4

I am looking for a way how to manipulate the main menu of an `e4` `RCP` application.
The menu should have different items enabled, depending on the current `Perspective`.

So far, I came up with the solution to use the `@CanExecute` annotation for each menu handler to check for the active perspective like so:

```
@CanExecute
public boolean canExecute(MPerspective activePerspective) {
    return (activePerspective.getElementId().equals("somePerspectiveName"));
}
```

Is there any better way how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to control if the menu item is enabled/disabled what you have is OK.

You can control the visibility of the menu item by specifying a 'Visible-When Expression' in the 'Handled Menu Item' entry in the Application.e4xmi. Here you specify the id of a 'core expression' defined using the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions` extension point.